# Какой способ все таки лучше?

Tags: архитектура

Решил все таки для себя написать скрипт системы активной рекламы.

Но уже дней 10 наверное не могу определиться каким способом процедурным или ООП начать писать проект?

После глубокого изучения обоих способов могу сделать вывод что, процедурный быстрее, а ООП гибче.

Но как поступить в данном случае (ведь система изначально должна проектироваться как высоко-нагруженная?

Comment: Каким методом лучше владеешь, тем и пиши.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбор применяемой парадигмы зависит от удобства и желания программиста, только когда это самое удобство, а значит и скорость написания, являются главными приоритетами в выполняемом проекте. Иначе говоря - "горячие пирожки прямо с колес", на эту тему можно почитать о методологии "Экстремального программирования". Если вы единственный участник проекта и никто кроме вас в этом ковыряться больше не будет, а размер проекта (трудоемкость проектирования и исполнения) таков, что он полностью помещается в голове, то да - функциональное программирование подходит более чем (это уже ИМХО).

Answer (score 0):

Писать можно еще функциональным способом =) При грамотной реализации это даст возможность спокойно масштабировать систему. А вообще согласен с пользователем **Зоркий** - пишите так, как Вам удобнее.

Comment: Есть где кроме вики почитать про парадигмы программирования доступным языком? Я как бы владею ООП, и чисто на функциях умею, и процедурами (ссылки/указатели знаю и все такое), но у меня ощущение, что какие-то "изюминки" я упустил.

Comment: Сложно сказать. Крутых учебников, написанных доступным языком не видел. Думаю, что нужно просто писать и набираться опыта практическим путем.

Comment: Тогда вопрос проще - какая связь между масштабированиям и функциями?

Comment: А прямая. Если писать без побочных эффектов (а ФП этому активно способствуют), то автоматом получаете возможность распараллеливать процесс выполнения.

Comment: Не совсем понял, ну да ладно, спасибо)

Comment: Ну, например, из той же википедии:
> Ещё одним преимуществом функциональных программ является то, что они предоставляют широчайшие возможности для автоматического распараллеливания вычислений. Поскольку отсутствие побочных эффектов гарантировано, в любом вызове функции всегда допустимо параллельное вычисление двух различных параметров — порядок их вычисления не может оказать влияния на результат вызова.

Не говоря уже о том как прекрасно параллелится исполнение алгоритма map для списков :-)

Comment: Все, въехал) Да, про изюминки я прав оказался. Всегда писал "применимо к случаю и чтоб симпатично".